# Detect presence of coloured text in a cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

A client provide me with a set of data updates to a system that I support.  The way they done this is by providing an excel spreadsheet with ALL data where some updates have been made. They further updated the colour of the changed text only from black to some hue of blue, so the cell may look like this:

[image]

The spreadsheet is over 1000 rows long by about 20 columns wide, with many cells containing multi-line texts.  Most cells are not changed, but about 5% of cells have such blue updates.  How can I determine using a formula (or lacking that, a macro) whether the cell contains such change?  I can then do at least some automation to get the changes I need to make, rather than manually inspecting 20,000 cells.

Comment: Can't you just filter by the color yellow, remove the backcolor for those cells when you are done, and then they can repeat?

Comment: [this may be of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949079/vba-to-find-the-font-color-of-a-string)

Comment: @EricF I think I didn't expect myself correctly.  Background colour is irrelevant - it means something completely different. I need to detect presence of light-blue parts of texts inside the cell.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Yay! That did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: The page posted by cybernetic.nomad shows you how to do that with VBA.  The AbleBits Excel add-in (a paid add-in) has a tool for finding cells based on font or text color.